# Flutter - Update parant widget class UI on child button click

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[image]

I have such kind of scenario

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text("Hello"),
  ),
  body: Container(
    child: ChildWidget(
      listControl: this.sentToScreenBuildJson,
      notifyParent: refresh,
    ),
  ),
);
}
```

this is my parent build method where I have added ChildWidget a another statfulscreen and passing is a json and a refresh funtion

as per json child will able to draw UI
and on button click I am able to get callback to refresh method.

```
refresh() {
print("I get refreshed from child");
setState(() {
  print("I get refreshed from child in setState");
  this.sentToScreenBuildJson = this.newJson;
});
}
```

on button click both print get execute but UI is not updating as per newJson. 
Like I am expecting that as setState run parent has to call build with passing updated json.
which is not working.

thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you post the code for ChildWidget?

Answer (score 1):

When you want to pass data from Child to Parent you should use [`NotificationListener`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NotificationListener-class.html) at parent and dispatch [`Notification`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Notification-class.html) from child.

Instance of `Notification` class will be having data that you can consume in Parent using `NotificationListener`.

Mostly all the Flutter Widgets are using this technique, for example tab controller receive `OverscrollNotification` when user reaches to the last tab and still try to swipe.

Following is the demo that you can use to understand how you can use `NotificationListener` in your code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(ParentWidget());

class ParentWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  ParentWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ParentWidgetState createState() => _ParentWidgetState();
}

class _ParentWidgetState extends State<ParentWidget> {
    String _text = 'You have not pressed the button yet';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: NotificationListener<IntegerNotification>(
          onNotification: (IntegerNotification notification) {
            setState(() {
              print(notification);
             _text = 'You have pressed button ${notification.value} times'; 
            });
            return true;
          },
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(_text),
              ChildWidget(),
            ],
          )
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ChildWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const ChildWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ChildWidgetState createState() => _ChildWidgetState();
}

class _ChildWidgetState extends State<ChildWidget> {
  int _counter = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RaisedButton(onPressed: (){
      IntegerNotification(++_counter).dispatch(context);
    },child: Text('Increment counter'),);
  }
}

@immutable
class IntegerNotification extends Notification{
  final int value;

  const IntegerNotification(this.value);

  String toString(){
    return value.toString();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Update parant widget class UI on child button click

This is a common use case in flutter and flutter has built in [InheritedWidget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InheritedWidget-class.html) class for these kind of purpose. You may either directly use it for your purpose or use some ready made package solution which uses `InheritedWidget` behind the scenes like [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider).

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to @Darish's answer, you can declare a static variable in your `class 1`, access that static variable in `class 2` and then update the state of the variable in the `class 2`.

**For example:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Demo extends StatefulWidget {
  static UserObject userObject;

  @override
  _Demo createState() => _Demo();
}

class _Demo extends State<Demo> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    Demo.userObject = new UserObject(name: "EXAMPLE NAME");
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xfff3f3f3),
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("DEMO")),
        body: InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.push(context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HeroClass()));
            },
            child: Center(
                child: Hero(
                    tag: "tag-demo-id",
                    child: Container(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                        child: Text("${Demo.userObject.name} -> CLICK HERE",
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)))))));
  }
}

class HeroClass extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HeroClassState createState() => _HeroClassState();
}

class _HeroClassState extends State<HeroClass> {
  final myController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    myController.text = Demo.userObject.name;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Clean up the controller when the widget is removed from the widget tree.
    // This also removes the _printLatestValue listener.
    myController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("DEMO HERO")),
        body: Hero(
            tag: "tag-demo-id",
            child: Container(
              child: TextField(
                controller: myController,
              ),
            )),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              Demo.userObject.name = myController.text;
            });
          },
          child: Icon(Icons.save),
        ));
  }
}

// object class
class UserObject {
  String name;

  UserObject({this.name});

  UserObject.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    name = json['name'];
  }
}
```